# Can I define FIXED BackOff Strategy for JMSTemplate producer

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

If the broker is down/unreachable the Spring JMS producer shall wait for a configurable duration before retrying.
Is it possible to give a configuration like FixedBackOff in DefaultMessageListenerContainers ?

The problem is that I saw my producer is trying limitlessly to connect to an ActiveMQ broker, but the producer connection does not have a valid certificate chain and throws SSL error. This connection retry is without break and generates bunch of log entries in seconds. 
This is just a scenario that SSL was not correct but in production the broker is brought down for maintenance then the producer shall wait between connection retries.

Or is there a way to check the JMS Producer connection status before publishing messages.

**Environment**: Spring JMS. ActiveMQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed an option on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to configure:

```
/**
 * Specify the {@link BackOff} instance to use to compute the interval
 * between recovery attempts. If the {@link BackOffExecution} implementation
 * returns {@link BackOffExecution#STOP}, this listener container will not further
 * attempt to recover.
 * <p>The {@link #setRecoveryInterval(long) recovery interval} is ignored
 * when this property is set.
 * @since 4.1
 */
public void setBackOff(BackOff backOff) {
    this.backOff = backOff;
}
```

By default it is this one:

```
private BackOff backOff = new FixedBackOff(DEFAULT_RECOVERY_INTERVAL,  Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

The `Long.MAX_VALUE` argument stands for the `maxAttempts`.

**UPDATE**

If we are talking about a `JmsTemplate`, then the retry logic has to be done from the client code perspective. This one is a *passive* component and there is no any background threads doing some work like in case of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

For the purpose of client-based retries we suggest a [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) project. There is a `RetryTemplate` and `RetryPolicy` to configure. Then you just call that `JmsTemplate` with the `RetryTemplate.execute()` wrapper - and any errors will be retried according the policy.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I am looking for BackOff in JmsTemplet connection. Not in DMLC.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.